# Change text color of array adapter from java

Tags: android-arrayadapter

Here's my java code;

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ListView lvLokacije;
String sLista, class;
Class<?> ourClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lvLokacije = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLokacije);

    String lista[] = { "Class1", "Class2", "Class3", "EXIT", };

    ArrayAdapter<String> aLista = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,
                 R.layout.costum_list_item2, lista);
        lvLokacije.setAdapter(aLista);

         lvLokacije.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                     int myItemInt, long mylng) {

                sLista = (String) (lvLokacije.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                String ispis = sLista.toString();

                if (ispis.contentEquals("Class1")) {
                    class= "myClass1";
                } else if (ispis.contentEquals("Class2")) {
                    class= "myClass2";
                } else if (ispis.contentEquals("Class3")) {
                    class= "myClass3";
                }  else if (ispis.contentEquals("IZLAZ")) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }

                try {
                    ourClass = Class.forName("crni03.obracun." + class);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Main.this, ourClass);

                startActivity(ourIntent);

            }
        });     
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // This above line close correctly
}
```

}

here's costum_list_item2 XML;

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFF4D"
    android:textSize="19sp" />
```

I set text color in costum_list_item2 but i would like to change it from java but I don't know how.
I want a feature where the user can change the color of list items.

When I change `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to `android:id="@+id/text1"` 
I can create a TextView and call that id but that's as far as I can go.
Whenever I try to do something with that TextViev I get a null.pointer.exeption error.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the textview here. As each textview is a child element within a view with id 'lvLokacije'. what is lvLokacije here. If it is either listview or gridview then you can access the rows of the view using getView() method. This is how I got it working where position is the zero-based index of the elements in the listview.

```
ListView listView;
String list[] = { "TEXT", "TEXT2", "TEXT3", "TEXT4"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListCellAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public class ListCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context ctx;
    TextView txtView;
    public ListCellAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super();
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_list_item2, parent, false);
        }
        txtView = ((TextView)(row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)));
        txtView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        if(position == 1)
        {
            txtView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        else
        {
            txtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to do that. If You could give me some code example

Comment: I edited my previous post. It includes sample code now that is working. Please go through it.

Comment: I went trough it but i dont know how to display items of String list[].

Comment: In the above code, you can set it this way, txtView.setText(list[position]);

Comment: It's OK now, thanx for your help. But now i got another problem. I don't know how to set OnItemClickListener. I'll post my original code in first post if You can help! Thanx!

Comment: ListCellAdapter can implement OnItemClickListener and override OnClick method in it.

Comment: Thanx for Your help. I posted the code after You helped my if anybody else will have the same problem. I'll give You vote up as soon as i get 15 rep. :) Thanx again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Durga!!!
This is my code after it's been helped by Durga

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ListView lvLokacije;
String class;
Class<?> ourClass;

 String list[] = { "Class1", "Class2", "Class3",
         "EXIT", };

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
     lvLokacije = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLokacije);
     ListAdapter adapter = new ListCellAdapter(this);
    lvLokacije.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

 public class ListCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
         OnItemClickListener {
     Context ctx;
     TextView txtView;

     public ListCellAdapter(Context context) {
         super();
         ctx = context;
         lvLokacije.setOnItemClickListener(this);
     }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.length;
    }

     public Object getItem(int arg0) {
         return null;
     }

     public long getItemId(int arg0) {
         return 0;
     }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View row = convertView;
         if (row == null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_list_item2, parent,
                    false);
         }
        txtView = ((TextView) (row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)));
        txtView.setText(String.valueOf(list[position]));

         txtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

         return row;
    }

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Object oList = (list[arg2]);
            String ispis = sList.toString();
            if (ispis.contentEquals("Class1")) {
                class = "myClass1";
            } else if (ispis.contentEquals("Class2")) {
                class = "myClass2";
            } else if (ispis.contentEquals("Class3")) {
                class = "myClass3";
            }  else if (ispis.contentEquals("EXIT")) {
                onBackPressed();                
            }
            try {
                ourClass = Class.forName("crni03.obracun." + class);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Main.this, ourClass);

            startActivity(ourIntent);


    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // This above line close correctly
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}